# How to define functoin poiner(__fastcall) to call in linux gcc?

Tags: c, windows, gcc, kernel

In windows I used

```
__try {
    __int64(__fastcall * calladdress)(__int64, __int64);
    calladdress = (__int64*)par1;
    returnvalue = calladdress(par2, par3);
    }
    __except (EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER) {
    returnvalue = 0;
    }
```

In linux,

```
ptr64 functionaddr = data[0];
ptr64 par1 = data[1];
ptr64 par2 = data[2];
void * returnAddr = (void*) data[3];

ptr64(__fastcall* calladdress(ptr64,ptr64);
calladdress = (ptr64*)functionaddr;
*(ptr64*)returnAddr = calladdress(par1,par2);
```

```
Error: expected ')' befor '*' token

ptr64(__fastcall* calladdress(ptr64,ptr64);
                ^ here
```

Sorry for newbie question, but I don't know much about gcc.

It worked well in Windows, but I don't know how to compile this code on Linux.

If you know how to solve this problem, please reply.

Comment: I found that the ) token was missing from my code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't know much about Linux, so I can't guarantee that my answer is exactly right.

Just a quick search showed that the Linux kernel seems to be using fastcall like this.

```
#define FASTCALL(x) x __attribute__((regparm(3)))
#define fastcall __attribute__((regparm(3)))
```

More references:
[x86 gcc compiled assembly code: fastcall behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39628204/x86-gcc-compiled-assembly-code-fastcall-behavior)